# Jest Global Plugin in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am trying to mock out a plugin that runs on the `created()` hook inside a jest unit test, however, I keep getting back `TypeError: this.$translations is not a function` which is causing all my tests to fail with that error:

Inside the `Component` file:

```js
created () {
  this.$translations(this.page.translations)
}
```

Inside the `Test` file:

```js
import { translations } from '~/helpers/plugins/translations'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(translations)

const wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent, {
  localVue,
  propsData
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this, what i had to do was use `mocks` to mock the `this.$translations()` as a function:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(TBase, {
  localVue,
  mocks: { $translations: () => {} },
  propsData
})
```